# Update query not working in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

there are already values inside the texboxes which i filtered inside the table(score) but i wanna update it by changing the values inside on it and click update.

Can anyone help with my code..i wanna update the values inside the (texboxes) but my code wont work can anyone help me locate the code that messing with the program?

php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
//1
$u1id = $_POST['id1'];
$u1name = $_POST['name1'];
$u1score1 = $_POST['optA1'];
$u1score2 = $_POST['optB1'];
$u1other_qual = $_POST['other_qual1'];
$u1interview = $_POST['interview1'];
$u1total = $_POST['total1'];
//2
$u2id = $_POST['id2'];
$u2name = $_POST['name2'];
$u2score1 = $_POST['optA2'];
$u2score2 = $_POST['optB2'];
$u2other_qual = $_POST['other_qual2'];
$u2interview = $_POST['interview2'];
$u2total = $_POST['total2'];
//1
mysql_query("UPDATE score SET score1='$u1score1', score2='$u1score2', total='$u1total' WHERE id='$u2id'");
//2
mysql_query("UPDATE score SET score1='$u2score1', score2='$u2score2', total='$u2total' WHERE id='$u2id'");
}
?>
```

html code:

```
<form method="post" id="frm" name="frm" action="" />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
ID: <br />
<input type="text" name="id1" value="<?php if(empty($id[0])){$id[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $id[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="id2" value="<?php if(empty($id[1])){$id[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $id[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Name: <br />
<input type="text" name="name1" value="<?php if(empty($name[0])){$name[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $name[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="name2" value="<?php if(empty($name[1])){$name[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $name[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 1: <br />
<input type="text" name="optA1" value="<?php if(empty($score1[0])){$score1[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score1[0];} ?>" onchange="optTotal1()" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optA2" value="<?php if(empty($score1[1])){$score1[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score1[1];} ?>" onchange="optTotal2()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 2: <br />
<input type="text" name="optB1" value="<?php if(empty($score2[0])){$score2[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score2[0];} ?>" onchange="optTotal1()" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optB2" value="<?php if(empty($score2[1])){$score2[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score2[1];} ?>" onchange="optTotal2()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Other Qualification: <br />
<input type="text" name="other_qual1" value="<?php if(empty($other_qual[0])){$other_qual[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $other_qual[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="other_qual2" value="<?php if(empty($other_qual[1])){$other_qual[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $other_qual[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Interview: <br />
<input type="text" name="interview1" value="<?php if(empty($interview[0])){$interview[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $interview[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="interview2" value="<?php if(empty($interview[1])){$interview[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $interview[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Total: <br />
<input type="text" name="total1" value="<?php if(empty($total[0])){$total[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $total[0];} ?>" readonly onKeyUp="optTotal1()" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="total2" value="<?php if(empty($total[1])){$total[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $total[1];} ?>" readonly onKeyUp="optTotal2()" /> <br />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="update" />
</form>
```

Comment: what dumps php as error? mysql_query is obsoleted I would not use that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="update" />
```

You have given it a value, but not a name. If you change it to:

```
<input type="submit" name="update" value="yespleasedososir" />
```

it will end up in your post var

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts: 1. Have you echoed out your sql statements to see what you are getting? 2. Try add the tilde symbol before and after each column name...like `score1` = 'whatever'. 3. You should really be using the mysqli statemnts.